# Can I abort (not timeout) a long running query in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

If my application initiates a long-running (minutes) query in ArangoDB, can it be (programmatically) interrupted or aborted at my discretion - and without killing the server?

I searched the ArangoDB documentation, google group, and the web and haven’t been able to confirm whether this feature exists or not.  Sometimes a feature like this exists, but is not easily discovered.

I did find in “startTraversal” a “maxIterations” parameter, but I cannot predetermine when I want to terminate the query - it is dictated by user input.  I need an asynchronous way to terminate the operation.

Some graph DB’s have a “TIMEOUT” configuration; however, even this would not satisfy my requirement to abort the query at my discretion (any time.)

In my application (and many others I would think?)  the user may change his mind and select some other feature that effectively requires a new query of the (large) graph, and makes the first query unnecessary.  We don’t want to leave that query running and consuming resources.  We also don’t want to lose other pending queries or have to restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to terminate a traversal. I suggest to enter a feature request at https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues

Update: Versio 2.0.6 now officially supports aborting long running queries using asny requests.

Comment: I have talked to one of our developer. It seems not to be hard to add a kill for a running query. If you require this feature, please issue a request at https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues?state=open

Comment: This is an absolute requirement for my application.  I will definitely submit a request.  Thank you for your responsiveness.  I am blown away so far by ArangoDB capabilities and the support!

Comment: Is the short-term solution provided in the issue https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues/782 sufficient for you?